# Multiple war deployment Tomcat without blocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have one unique instance with three war :

- Aapp.war
- Bapp.war
- Capp.war

The Capp need a wsdl endpoint exposed by the Bapp.
I know it's not great, but I need to find a temporary solution without a big refactoring in existing architecture.

The problem is even if the Aapp.war and Bapp.war are deployed, when tomcat begin to deploy the Capp, it lock everything because the bean which instanciate the Bapp Wsdl client does not respond :

```
@Bean
    public WsStorageService getCustomerOfferStorageWSClient(){
        WsStorageService wsClient = null;
        String wsdlUrlProperty = prop.getCosWSApplicationServicesUrl();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(wsdlUrlProperty);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        wsClient = new WsService_Service(url).getWsServicePort();
        return wsClient ;
    }
```

I cannot call http://myserver/Aapp or http://myserver/Bapp until the Capp is deployed successfully.
Why ?

Comment: It is not an answer to your question (why Tomcat locks up), but why don't you make a copy of the WSDL from B and either bundle it as a static resource in C where it is needed or publish it as a static file with another web server? The contract for the service should not change, so the WSDL should not need to be generated every time. Then you can create the bean without calling B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact it's not really the WSDL, it's the WS url. If I get the WSDL in static resources, how the code could know the URL to call to have answer ? The contract does not change, but the target server change. I have several environment (dev, qualif...) which each have specific data return by this WS.

Comment: You already have that problem with wsdlUrlProperty, which must be obtained from somewhere if it can vary between environments. A best practice is to set ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY instead. See for example https://medium.com/@nieldw/setting-the-target-endpoint-url-on-java-soap-web-service-clients-d5079da7816 (first hit I got on Google).

Comment: I could not really resolve the problem, so I create a new Tomcat instance for this war.